# How can I unlock more adventures?

Tags: guild-of-dungeoneering

I'm pretty stuck with just one adventure to do, and it's hard.

[image]

Is there a way to unlock more adventures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that unlocking more adventures is done by ending adventures.
Sometimes (like in the given case), it's the last one for the current chapter and finishing it will unlock more.

[image]

Comment: This really seems like a non-answer.  The answer to "I'm stuck on this dungeon, how do I complete it?" can't possibly be "Complete the dungeon".

Comment: @Mike: I know, but as a nob I was stuck, and asked, and the answer was as simple as that. No one answered for a while, so I decided to post an answer to anyone interested later on. I've posted it as a wiki, so anyone can edit and add..